# Electron - size limit on IPC messages for displaying image in a new window

Tags: electron

I am trying to display a image in a new window from my electron app using BrowserWindow. The image is dynamically  generated from the main app. To do so, my current implementation sends the image data from the main window via IPC to then use window.loadURL to load the image.

I notice that if the image data is too long, then it will not send it.

I've tried looking around the documentation and experimenting with various sizes shows that there seems to be a limit.

If there is a limit on how much can be sent, what is it? And is it OS dependent?

Comment: One will always see a limit in speed and size of large amounts of data transferred via IPC. It may be easier to save the image to the local file system (even temporarily) and then send an IPC message to a newly created window to open / display the image.